# Rendering an EGL Image to a frame buffer with GTK

Tags: c++, c, opengl-es, gtk

I'm trying to render an `EGLImageKHR` that I get from NVIDIA's decoder, to a frame buffer so I can render this frame buffer in the screen. I wrote a code that does the following:

Creates two textures, `frameBufferTexture` and `externalTexture`. We write our EGLImage to `externalTexture` and draw to `frameBufferTexture` from `externalTexture`. Then we read from `frameBufferTexture` with `glReadPixels`:

```
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    glGenTextures(1, &externalTexture);
    glGenTextures(1, &frameBufferTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameBufferTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, decodedNvFrame->width, decodedNvFrame->height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glUniform1i(texLocation, 0);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameBufferTexture);

    EGLImageKHR hEglImage;

    hEglImage = NvEGLImageFromFd(eglDisplay, decodedNvFrame->nvBuffer->planes[0].fd);
    if (!hEglImage)
        printf("Could not get EglImage from fd. Not rendering\n");
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameBufferTexture, 0);     
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, externalTexture);
    glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES(GL_TEXTURE_2D, hEglImage);
    glUniform1i(texLocation, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

    GLenum frameBufferStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (frameBufferStatus!=GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        printf("frameBufferStatus problem!\n");
        abort();
    }
    glReadPixels(0, 0, 512, 512, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, r);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        printf("%i ", r[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    NvDestroyEGLImage(eglDisplay, hEglImage);
```

See that I'm using glReadPixels to get just a piece of the frame buffer so I can see what's happening.

This is what I get in the output:

```
0 0 0 255 0 0 0 255 0 0 0 255 ...
```

which I guess comes from the `glTexImage2D` cal where I pass `0`. This means that `glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES` isn't pushing our image to the `externalTexture`.

Here's the fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(tex, TexCoord);
}
```

If I change this shader to `FragColor = vec4(1.0,texture(tex, TexCoord).r,0,1.0)` I get this output:

```
255 0 0 255 255 0 0 255 255 0 0 255 ...
```

which means the shader is working and is writing to the frame buffer.
If I put

```
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, d);
```

right after `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, externalTexture);`, I can see the contents of `d`, which means my fragment shader is writing data correctly from the texture `externalTexture`.

This puts the problem in `glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES`. It's not filling externalTexture with my image!

Why?

**ps**: I suspect of `eglDisplay`. Why do I need a display to create an `EGLImageKHR`? I've seen code from NVIDIA that uses `NvEGLImageFromFd` and passes an eglDisplay from an X11 window. But I'm in GTK and I don t get why an egl display is important, first of all because I'm rendering to a frame buffer, but secondly because I render to GTK's framebuffer when I want to render images.

Comment: `glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ...);` is not legal. `glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES` can only ever take `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` as a target.

Comment: @NicolBolas that's strnge, because no error happens after this call, and it apparently worked when I've read with glReadPixels. Also, I took it from where where he said it worked: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1028811/export-gl-texture-as-dmabuf/?offset=8#5384937. Do you have an alternative suggestion if not using `glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES`?

Comment: @NicolBolas it's also used here https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1030669/jetson-tx1/trying-to-process-with-opengl-an-eglimage-created-from-a-dmabuf_fd-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the example implementations in [nvidia](https://devtalk.nvidia.com)

```
tegra_multimedia_api\argus\samples\utils\PreviewConsumer.cpp
tegra_multimedia_api\samples\common\classes\NvEglRenderer.cpp
```